# Invalid solution of a complicated integral

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

I have an integral of the form

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\mu-1}e^{-\beta x} \Gamma\left( \nu,\alpha x \right)dx$$

where $\Gamma\left(s,x\right) = \int_{x}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. Using the answer provided by [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123849335/table-of-integrals-series-and-products) by Daniel Zwillinger (equation 6.455 page 657), the solution to this integral can be written as

$$\frac{\alpha^\nu \Gamma\left( \mu+\nu \right)}{\mu \left(\alpha + \beta\right)^{\mu+\nu}}{}_2F_1\left( 1,\mu+\nu;\mu+1;\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} \right) $$

where ${}_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). Unfortunately, in my case the parameters are defined as $\mu = m, \nu = -m, \alpha = \frac{m}{\omega}, \beta = -\frac{m}{\omega}$ which makes the solution invalid! What should I do in this case?
BTW I get a totally different solution by Mathematica which is written in terms of Polygamma function (It also becomes invalid). What should I do?!

Comment: Try expanding $\Gamma$ as a series https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7 and integrate term by term.

Comment: My (now-deleted) answer was mistaken.  Defining $u = \alpha x$, and assuming that $\beta = - \alpha$ we have
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\mu-1}e^{-\beta x} \Gamma\left( \nu,\alpha x \right)dx = \frac{1}{\alpha^\mu} \int_0^\infty y^{\mu-1}e^{y } \Gamma\left( \nu,y \right) dy$$which Mathematica says does not converge when $\mu = -\nu$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yeah man, thank you for the attempt anyway! I checked with Wolfram first and it said it does not converge however when you wrote the answer I thought Wolfram is wrong (cause Wolfram makes mistakes from time to time specially if one does not add the Assumption statement for the parameters). However I double checked it numerically and it diverges unfortunately!

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks for the tip sir, however I am not interested in series solutions, I need a closed form and the integral diverges unfortunately!